# fzn2smt solver answers with `unknown` on tested formulas

Tags: smt, minizinc, flatzinc

The [fzn2smt](http://ima.udg.edu/Recerca/lap/fzn2smt/index.html) tool allows one to solve *flatzinc* formulas via *Yices*.

When I try to run it, the solver answers with `UNKNOWN` to every formula I test. **e.g.**:

```sh
~$ java -Xmx4096M fzn2smt -ce "./yices-2.5.2/bin/yices -f" -i 2DPacking.fzn 
Time1:170
=====UNKNOWN=====
```

However, on the given example, it seems to correctly create the `2DPacking.fzn.smt` instance in the same directory of the [`2DPacking.fzn`](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/blob/master/tests/examples/2DPacking.mzn) file:

```sh
~$ ls
2DPacking.fzn.smt    2DPacking.fzn    2DPacking.mzn    2DPacking.ozn
```

If I manually run `Yices` over the `smt` formula, I get a positive result:

```sh
~$ yices-smt -f 2DPacking.fzn.smt 
sat

(= x____00002_6_ 0)
...

IMPLICANT:
(>= x____00003_4_ 0)
...
```

**Q:** Does anyone else have experience with `fzn2smt` and know how to fix this issue?

---

Just to be sure that the issue I am experiencing is not due to the installation part, I will share it here:

```sh
 main_dir
 main_dir/fzn2smt-2-0-02      # unpacked fzn2smt files
 main_dir/antlr               # unpacked antlr-runtime-3.5 files
 main_dir/yices-2.5.2         # unpacked yices files
```

I also modified the environment variables as requested by the tool instructions:

```sh
 PATH=${main_dir}/yices-2.5.2/bin/:${PATH}
 PATH=${main_dir}/fzn2smt-2-0-02/:${PATH}

 CLASSPATH=${main_dir}:${CLASSPATH}
 CLASSPATH=${main_dir}/antlr:${CLASSPATH}
 CLASSPATH=${main_dir}/fzn2smt-2-0-02:${CLASSPATH}
```

Comment: `fzn2smt` is a rather old tool, while you're using the newest version of Yices. This might just be unexpected output from Yices that `fzn2smt` doesn't yet understand. I know this won't help with your problem, but I'm afraid it is a bug in `fzn2smt`.

Comment: @Dekker you nailed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@Dekker* suggested in the comments, the issue is due to `fzn2smt` seemingly not being updated in a while.

After some trials and errors, I found out that the most recent version of `Yices` that appears to be compatible with `fzn2smt` is  version `2.2.1`.

It can be executed as follows:

```sh
~$ java -Xmx4096M fzn2smt -ce "./yices-2.2.1/bin/yices-smt -f" -i 2DPacking.fzn
Time1:162
Time: 207
Pos: 0
item = array2d(1..2, 1..4, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
obj = 1;
----------
Time: 223
Pos: 0
item = array2d(1..2, 1..4, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
obj = 1;
----------
==========
Time2:228
```

---

Originally, `fzn2smt` was coupled with version `2` of `Yices` presented at the *SMT-COMP 2009*. To use that version, the command-line instruction to use the tool is *slightly different*:

```sh
~$ java -Xmx4096M fzn2smt -ce "./yices2smt09/bin/yices -f" -i 2DPacking.fzn
Time1:160
Time: 208
Pos: 0
item = array2d(1..2, 1..4, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
obj = 1;
----------
==========
Time2:223
```

Notice that

- the executable is named `yices` here, rather than `yices-smt`
- the output is slightly different, for some reasons the solution is printed more than once when using the newer version of the tool

---

Old versions of `Yices` can be downloaded from [here](http://yices.csl.sri.com/download-old.html).